# Homemade PMOS LDO again, is a few millivolts of oscillation normal?

Tags: design, ldo, oscillation

After I walked through datasheets of different op-amps it turned out that I can live without the NMOS as a driver for the pass transistor, using `TL084` op amp (or its one unit sibling `TL081`) if the pullup resistor is large enough, e.g. 20k. Now I ran this in a simulator and I am getting a little bit of oscillation (several millivolts at the output, am I treading noise land if battling this?) is this normal or should I resolve this too?

Here is the circuit diagram, respect part numbers as those are exactly what I used. Google will be your friend in finding datasheets as everything is jellybean parts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fME2MX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This several millivolts oscillation result is taken from when I simulate with 1kHz 3Vp-p sinusoidal biased by 9V or 15V. Does this spell good regulation? The 10 ohm load seems pretty hard to satisfy.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a number of problems, and I'm not sure which one of them is biting you on the butt.

1) You don't show the *entire* connection for the TL431, but I assume that you've tied the reference input to the cathode so as to get 2.5 volts. Please check the data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf, figure 17. You must get rid of C1.

2) The fact that you needed a pullup resistor on the gate of your MOSFET should have told you something, and that something is that you need a different op amp. The TL081 is nowhere near a rail-to-rail output device. If you look at the output voltage swing figures you'll see that for +/- 5 volts, you can only count on ~+/- 3 volts when driving a 2k load. In your case, it means that without help you can't produce a high enough gate voltage to turn the MOSFET entirely off. When you say "if the pullup resistor is large enough, e.g. 20k", I assume you mean "if the pullup resistor is *small* enough, e.g. less than 20k".

Plus, you haven't mentioned the output voltage from this regulator, so I'm assuming 5 or 6 volts. This in turn suggests that your input voltage to the op amp is in the neighborhood of 1 volt. This is well outside the input common-mode range. You can try changing R4 to 1k and trying for 5 volts. This will let the op amp inputs run at about 2.5 volts, and that may make a difference.

Finallly, the gate capacitance of the MOSFET is listed as 3400 pF. Combined with the fact that you're at the hairy edge of what the op amp can drive, I wouldn't be surprised if this is a problem. Op amps typically have limited ability to drive capacitive loads while maintaining stability.

Comment: 1) Indeed I shorted the cathode and reference terminals of `TL431` together (or I would have used a different symbol). 2) `IRF4905` have a gate threshold voltage of about -2V and as long as the op amp can raise that high I believe not using a RR OPA is not a problem (you will always get a few millivolts across load due to leakage anyway, and I can select and match MOSFETs and OPAs)

Comment: Also this pull-up have to be large enough or the OPA's output swing won't go high enough to go beyond the MOSFET's threshold voltage and turn it off

Comment: If you have to select and match MOSFETs and op amps YOU NEED DIFFERENT OP AMPS!

Comment: Also - YOU MUST GET RID OF C1!

Comment: Chill, bro, no need to yell. I am going to try around with a few different OPAs I have (and have ordered) and see if there is a better match: `LM358`, `LM324`, `OPA2134`, `NE5532`, `OP07` and probably try some discrete solutions.

Comment: This circuit is part of my bench supply project so the output voltage is adjustable. The final design would be an adjustable mains SMPS chained to this LDO. The final design would feature d-pots as sampling and reference voltage dividers.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/an/slyt202/slyt202.pdf

Using the formula $$PSRR = 20 \log \frac{Input ripple}{Output ripple}$$ I get `20 log 3000 ~= 70db`. Which is exactly what the later graph shows as an example rejection ratio. So your regulator seems to have exactly normal performance here.

Comment: The thing is that the few millivolts oscillation have 10 times the frequency of the ripple I injected, and still exists when there is no ripple superimposed.

Comment: Well then the injected ripple is a red herring and your circuit is not stable. The other answer is right about capacitative loads. A small series resistor between the opamp and gate might help a bit; try between 10R and 100R.